# Picture box filling with some percentages

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am very new to C sharp programming. I have the design like as shown below attached image.

My concept is i have to set some volume in "Transfer volume" text box (for example 100) and then press "set" button. It automatically sets the scale of picture box, it is working fine.

Now i want to fill the picture box with colors when i click "Regenerate" button. The percentage of color to be filled in picture box should be the number in the TextBox of that regarding color or liquid.

for example 
if i set   GasPhase =5 ; Hydrocarbon Liquid =5; Water= 5; Oil Based Mud =5; Water Based Mud =5 ; Not Identified = 75.

then the picture has to fill with  75 % with "Not Identified" color and GasPhase color with 5 % e.t.c.

I have the written some code as shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


  namespace test
  {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void txtTransferVolume_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtTransferSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = txtTransferVolume.Text;
        double midvalue = Convert.ToDouble(value);
        lblTransferBottleMax.Text = value;
        lblTransferBottleMid.Text = (midvalue / 2).ToString();

    }

    private void chkTransferManual_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void btnTransferBottleRegenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

   }
 }
```

Please help me how to fill as i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily by drawing directly on the picturebox control or creating a bitmap in memory and show in the picturebox.

Example:

```
private void DrawPercentages(int[] percentages, Color[] colorsToUse)
{
   // Create a Graphics object to draw on the picturebox
   Graphics G = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

   // Calculate the number of pixels per 1 percent
   float pixelsPerPercent = pictureBox1.Height / 100f;

   // Keep track of the height at which to start drawing (starting from the bottom going up)
   int drawHeight = pictureBox1.Height;

   // Loop through all percentages and draw a rectangle for each
   for (int i = 0; i < percentages.Length; i++)
   {
       // Create a brush with the current color
       SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colorsToUse[i]);
       // Update the height at which the next rectangle is drawn.
       drawHeight -= (int)(pixelsPerPercent * percentages[i]);
       // Draw a filled rectangle
       G.FillRectangle(brush, 0, drawHeight, pictureBox1.Width, pixelsPerPercent * percentages[i]);
    }    
}
```

Of course you have to check that both arrays are the same length, etc. I just want to give you the basic idea of how to do this.

Here's a concept of how to get your data in arrays and pass them to the function. Since you are using a different textbox for each value, it's hard to iterate over them, so right now I'm showing you how to do it using the 6 values you have now.

```
private void btnTransferBottleRegenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int[] percentages = new int[6];
  percentages[0] = int.Parse(txtTransferNotIdentified.Text);
  percentages[1] = int.Parse(txtTransferWater.Text);
  // And so on for every textbox

  Color[] colors = new Color[6];
  colors[0] = Color.Red;
  colors[1] = Color.Yellow;
  // And so on for every color

  // Finally, call the method in my example above
  DrawPercentages(percentages, colors);
}
```

If your percentages don't always sum to 100, you could use a third parameter that specifies the sum and change the value `100f` to this value in the `DrawPercentages` method.

Comment: I'm just presenting you the concept of drawing by an example. Feel free to interpret it however you like, but I fail to see how collecting the data and passing it as arrays could be objective. You can also draw each rectangle on it's own line using the Graphics object, but I always like to keep it scalable. Any future additions of data would be no problem for my method, where as writing a line for each item in the data might require additional code.

Comment: Yes you are right, same i am also thinking how to collect the data from there(textBoxes and labels) and passing it through arrays.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to pass those entered values into array of percentages.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer, its working perfect. But small change is needed in your answer that array name to colors has to be changed.